# How should I use the rules provided by FPGrowth in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have generated association rules with FpGrowth algorithm in Spark.
Here is the code source:

```
val dataset = spark.createDataset(Seq("aaa bbbb eee","bbbb ccc eee","aaa bbbb")).map(t => t.split(" ")).toDF("items")

val fpgrowth = new FPGrowth().setItemsCol("items").setMinSupport(0.5).setMinConfidence(0.6)
val model = fpgrowth.fit(dataset)

model.freqItemsets.show()

model.associationRules.show()
```

But how can I use the generated rules to make predictions?

Comment: Related (unanswered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398873/how-should-i-use-the-rules-provided-by-fpgrowth-in-spark

Answer (score 1):

I am still struggling with the untyped Dataframe-Rows myself, so I can't tell you how you *should* use the rules. So I will only tell how you *could* use them. The solution is probably not very idiomatic.

Anyway... Here is the code that seems to work:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.fpm._

val dataset = spark.createDataset(Seq(
   "a b e","b c e", "a b", "a b e", "a b d e", 
   "a e c f", "a b f e", "a f c e",
   "c d w x", "c x p d", "p q c d", "c p d r a",
   "a c b d", "c d p q", "c r p d"
)).map(t => t.split(" ")).toDF("items")
val fpgrowth = new FPGrowth().setItemsCol("items").
  setMinSupport(0.3).setMinConfidence(0.5)
val model = fpgrowth.fit(dataset)
val rules = model.associationRules

val exampleShoppingCart = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
val proposals = rules.rdd.map{ rule => 
  val antecedent = rule.getAs[Seq[String]]("antecedent")
  val consequent = rule.getAs[Seq[String]]("consequent")
  if (antecedent.forall(exampleShoppingCart.contains)) {
    consequent.toSet
  } else {
    Set.empty[String]
  }
}.reduce(_ ++ _)

val nonTrivialProposals = proposals.filterNot(exampleShoppingCart.contains)

println(
  "Your shopping cart: " + exampleShoppingCart.mkString(",") + 
  "; You might also be interested in: " + nonTrivialProposals
)

// Output:
// Your shopping cart: a,b,c,d; You might also be interested in: Set(e, p)
```

Brief explanation: `model.associationRules` gives you a `Dataframe` with three columns: `antecedent`, `consequent` and `confidence`. If you want to use such a rule to make a proposal for an extension of a given transaction `exampleShoppingCart`, then you have to check whether all items in `antecedent` occur in the transaction `exampleShoppingCart`. If this is the case, you can add all elements of the `consequent` to the proposal. If some of the items in `antecedent` don't occur in the transaction, then the rule does not match, and you don't propose anything (`Set.empty`). Once you've computed all the proposals from all the rules, simply reduce them into one single proposal. Finally, you probably want to remove the items which are already contained in the transaction anyway (this is what the `filter` is good for).

It would be interesting to find out how to reduce the set of rules to an smaller equivalent set of rules, where for example if `{x} => {y}` is contained, then `{x, z} => {y}` is not repeated.

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I use the generated rules to make predictions?

It is as simple as:

```
model.transform(dataset).show()
// +----------------+----------+
// |           items|prediction|
// +----------------+----------+
// |[aaa, bbbb, eee]|        []|
// |[bbbb, ccc, eee]|     [aaa]|
// |     [aaa, bbbb]|     [eee]|
// +----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Oh well... The idiomatic solution takes a single line, who would have thought that? +1